# using Order By and Left or right join in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

Please consider this table:

```
Min            Max            Desc
------------------------------------------------
10             24             Total
10             14             Between 10 and 14
15             19             Between 15 and 19
20             24             Between 20 and 24
```

and this `CTE`:

```
with p as
(
   SELECT top 100 percent [min],
                          [max],
                          [Desc]
    FROM   [MyBoundaries]
    ORDER BY rownumber
)
select 
    p.[Desc],
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 0 AND tbl.col_2 < 5) THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 5 AND tbl.col_2 < 10) THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 10 AND tbl.col_2 < 15) THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 15 AND tbl.col_2 < 20) THEN 1 END)
from [dbo].[MyTable] AS tbl
   inner join p on tbl.col_1 >= p.min and tbl.col_1 <= p.max
where tbl.[YEAR] = 2020
group by p.[Desc]
```

I have multiple problem with this `CTE`:

1. The order of the records in `[MyBoundaries]` is not maintained and I want the results to be exactly in the order of the table `[MyBoundaries]`.
2. If I haven't record in boundary `(20, 24)` then this boundary not included in the output, but I want:

   ```
   Between 20 and 24           0           0           0          0
   ```

I changed `inner join` to `left` or 'right` join but output not changed.

How can I solve these problems?

Thanks

Comment: There is no order to the rows in a table. Table operators don't have any sense of order; so it's not clear what you think you would input order for if you had it. Result sets have (partial) order. Order by without limit/top that is not at the outermost level is a no-op. Explain what you expect & why you expect it--with justification referencing authoritative documentation. Otherwise we can't address your misconceptions & can only rewrite documenation--without knowing what you are misinterpreting. Also: Wrong code & no expectations does not tell us what you want. [mre]

Comment: Notice how all the proposed solutions include an order by clause in the outer query. This is directly related to phil's comment and extends it. Rows in resultset also have no particular order unless the query that generates it also has an order by clause. A GROUP by clause tends to lead to the appearance of order due to the query plan - but there is no guarantee without that ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
select 
    p.[Desc],
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 0 AND tbl.col_2 < 5) THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 5 AND tbl.col_2 < 10) THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 10 AND tbl.col_2 < 15) THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE when (tbl.col_2 >= 15 AND tbl.col_2 < 20) THEN 1 END),
from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE [YEAR] = 2020) AS tbl -- filter on source
right join [MyBoundaries] p on tbl.col_1 >= p.min and tbl.col_1 <= p.max -- right join
group by p.[Desc]
order by MIN(p.[rownumber]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good place of a lateral join:

```
select b.[Desc], t.*
from [MyBoundaries] b
outer apply (
    select 
        sum(case when t.col_2 >=  0 and t.col_2 <  5 then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when t.col_2 >=  5 and t.col_2 < 10 then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when t.col_2 >= 10 and t.col_2 < 15 then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when t.col_2 >= 15 and t.col_2 < 20 then 1 else 0 end)
    from [dbo].[MyTable] t
    where t.col_1 >= b.min and t.col_1 <= b.max and t.year = 2020
) t
order by b.rownumber
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple changes to do what you want:

- You can use `left join`, but the table where you want to keep all the rows needs to be first.
- The CTE needs to return `rownumber`, so you can include that in the `order by`.
- Filtering on the other table needs to be in the `on` clause.

So:

```
with b as (
      SELECT b.*
      FROM [MyBoundaries] b
      ORDER BY rownumber
     )
select b.[Desc],
       COUNT(CASE when tbl.col_2 >= 0 AND tbl.col_2 < 5 THEN 1 END),
       COUNT(CASE when tbl.col_2 >= 5 AND tbl.col_2 < 10 THEN 1 END),
       COUNT(CASE when tbl.col_2 >= 10 AND tbl.col_2 < 15 THEN 1 END),
       COUNT(CASE when tbl.col_2 >= 15 AND tbl.col_2 < 20 THEN 1 END)
from b left join
     [dbo].[MyTable]  tbl
     on tbl.col_1 >= b.min and tbl.col_1 <= b.max and
        tbl.[YEAR] = 2020
group by b.[Desc] 
order by b.rownumber;
```

I changed the CTE name to `b` because that makes more sense for "boundaries".  Also, I recommend that you avoid using names like `desc`, `min`, and `max` which are a SQL reserved words as column names -- as well as `year` which is a keyword and could become reserved in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the query could look something like this

```
with p_cte as (
    select top 100 percent [min], [max], [Desc]
    from MyBoundaries)
select pc.[Desc]
       sum(case when (t.col_2 >= 0 and t.col_2 < 5) then 1 end) ZeroToFive,
       sum(case when (t.col_2 >= 5 and t.col_2 < 10) then 1 end) FiveToTen,
       sum(case when (t.col_2 >= 10 and t.col_2 < 15) then 1 end) TenToFifteen,
       sum(case when (t.col_2 >= 15 and t.col_2 < 20) then 1 end) FiftennToTwenty
from p_cte pc
     left join [dbo].[MyTable] t on pc.[min] <= t.col_1 
                                    and pc.[max] >= t.col_1
                                    and t.[YEAR] = 2020
group by pc.[Desc]
order by pc.[min], pc.[Desc] desc;
```